# Rails: Trying to Format output of Acts_As_Taggable tag in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

In my `_updates.html.haml` file in my home view of my rails app, I am accessing
a bunch of posts with the `@posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])` in my home controller. I am doing an each iteration on `@posts` and am trying to prepend a '#' symbol in front of the tag name so that the '#' is part of the link in the link_to statement.

I am trying the following but I get a typeerror.

```
  %ul
    - post.tags.each do |tag|
      - tag_plus_hash = '#' + tag
      %li= link_to tag_plus_hash, posts_path(tag: tag.name)
```

My error is the following:

```
can't convert ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag into String
```

Comment: Try calling the method `to_s`, like so `tag.to_s`

Comment: @LuísRamalho Thank you Infinitely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the method `to_s`, like so

```
  %ul
    - post.tags.each do |tag|
      - tag_plus_hash = '#' + tag.to_s
      %li= link_to tag_plus_hash, posts_path(tag: tag.name)
```

Or even better, use interpolation

```
  %ul
    - post.tags.each do |tag|
      - tag_plus_hash = "##{tag}"
      %li= link_to tag_plus_hash, posts_path(tag: tag.name)
```